# How to add hyperlinked text in UITextView which runs custom function when clicked

Tags: swift, uitextview, nsattributedstring

How can I add hyperlinked text in a UITextView so that when it is clicked, a custom function in my app is called. Basically, my intention is to show a little popup window that gives more information on the clicked-upon word(s), similar to how Wikipedia works –

[image]

I read in this [Hacking With Swift article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-make-tappable-links-in-nsattributedstring) that you can "use custom URL schemes, e.g. yourapp://" in attributed text, but I'm confused how yourapp://... links to a particular function within your app? What would my `URL` be?

The code they talk about in the article is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Want to learn iOS? You should visit the best source of free iOS tutorials!")
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "https://www.hackingwithswift.com", range: NSRange(location: 19, length: 55))

        textView.attributedText = attributedString
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.open(URL)
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL can be whatever you want as long as you have a way to parse/compare it in your `shouldInteractWith` function:

For example, you might make it `myapp://ACTION_NAME`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Want to learn iOS? You should visit the best source of free iOS tutorials!")
        attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "myapp://action1", range: NSRange(location: 19, length: 55))

        textView.attributedText = attributedString
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith url: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
        switch url.absoluteString {
        case "myapp://action1":
           //perform some sort of action here
           break
        case "myapp://action2":
           //perform another sort of action here
           break
        default:
           //if it isn't a link that is recognized by the app, assume it should get opened by the system instead
           UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
        }
        
        return false
    }
}
```

The above is just the very basic concept. In a real-world application, I might do a little more work to compare the URLs -- maybe first look at `url.scheme` to check if it was equal to `myapp` and then split the action name out. You could also make an `enum` of action types to make the whole thing more type safe.